# Create a drag and drop feature for a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code till now:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<title>
        Drag and Drop
</title>
<style>

    #timetable {
        float: left;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #timetable td{
        width: 150px;
        height: 75px;
        border: 1px solid black;

    }
    td div{
        width: 150px;
        height: 75px;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .drag{
        width:150px;
        height:75px;
        border :2px solid red;
    }
    .list{
        float: right;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 150px;
        height: 425px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".drag").draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            cursor: "crossshair"
        });
        $(".drop").droppable({
            accept: ".drag",
            hoverClass:"ui-state-highlight",
            tolerance:"pointer",
            drop: function(event,ui){
                console.log("drop");
                $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top:0,left:0}).appendTo($(this));
            }
        });
        $(".list").droppable({
            accept: (".drag"),
            hoverClass:"ui-state-highlight"
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<table id="timetable">
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
        <td><div class="drop"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="list">
    Drag from below:&nbsp;
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
    <div class="drag"></div>
</div>
```

I want items to be dropped back and arrange themselves to the scrollable column area. Items gets dropped back now but doesn't arrange itself(and also changes colour :( ).

Also I want some idea as how to uniquely identify the cell in the table where an item is being dropped as I am going to have a table made in my database which stores what was dropped in a particular cell.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: When you drop take the target contents and copy it into the destination. That way you don't need to mess with coordinates and everything appears to snap into place. For ids there are many options `id` attribute or  a custom `data-id`.

Comment: @Jasen Could you please give a snippet for the first problem, I have tried but couldn't do it.It would really help a lot.

Comment: OK, I see what you are trying to do now. You'll need to borrow ideas from this example [photo manager](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager) and [shopping cart](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart). You'll need to implement your own sorting that triggers on the drop event.